# How to column stack arrays within a loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function generating a 2d array. I am running the function in a for loop to generate data. After the loop finishes, I want to have each of these 2d arrays  combined (horizontally stacked) so that I can export it to a csv file.

I figured out that the column_stack function is useful to stack the arrays in the way I want. Let say "results" is the 2d array returned by my function. If I have an initial array I can stack it up the way I want. I have no initial array at this point.
However, is there any way I can generate an array in the for loop and append the other 2d arrays from the following iterations

```
np.column_stack((results,results))


array([[-2.7532e-03,  1.1973e-06, -2.7532e-03,  1.1973e-06],
       [ 9.7603e-02,  1.9542e-06,  9.7603e-02,  1.9542e-06],
       [ 1.9770e-01,  2.0952e-06,  1.9770e-01,  2.0952e-06],
       [ 2.9758e-01,  2.1637e-06,  2.9758e-01,  2.1637e-06],
       [ 3.9787e-01,  1.4734e-06,  3.9787e-01,  1.4734e-06],
       [ 4.9795e-01,  1.3670e-06,  4.9795e-01,  1.3670e-06],
       [ 5.9790e-01,  2.0252e-06,  5.9790e-01,  2.0252e-06],
       [ 6.9817e-01,  2.1771e-06,  6.9817e-01,  2.1771e-06],
       [ 7.9837e-01,  1.2704e-06,  7.9837e-01,  1.2704e-06],
       [ 8.9822e-01,  2.1794e-06,  8.9822e-01,  2.1794e-06],
       [ 9.9847e-01,  1.4442e-06,  9.9847e-01,  1.4442e-06]])
```

Here is what i am exactly trying to do:

```
from xtralien import *
from numpy import *


### 1.Sweep Settings ###
vstart = 0  #Starting Voltage (V)
vend = 1    #End Voltage (V)
vstep = 0.1 #Step Size (V)
smu = 'SMU1'

### 2.Create Variables ###
vnum = ((vend-vstart)/vstep) + 1 #Calculate number of steps in sweep
volts = linspace(vstart,vend,vnum) #Create voltage list

### 3. Perform Sweep ###
with X100.USB('COM5') as Dev1: #Connect to the Device via USB
    for i in [1,2,3,4,5]: ################This list is just an example. in the program it might be of any length!!
        Dev1['SMU2'].oneshot(i)
        results = vstack([Dev1[smu].oneshot(v) for v in volts])
```

I want the all the results to be stacked up into a single one. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: So you want to generate a new array of size [Nx1] at each iteration and append it to `results`?

Comment: It is better to collect all the arrays in a list (`list.append`), and do one `column_stack` at the end.  Iterative stacking is slower, and harder to initial (as your question shows).  Note that you already use `vstack` correctly - applied to a list generated by the list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build an array that could be used as a initial value into which `column_vstack` other arrays, you can build it from a list of empty lists.

Demo:

```
res = np.array([[]] * 11)      # or better: res = np.zeros(

arr = np.array([[-2.7532e-03,  1.1973e-06, -2.7532e-03,  1.1973e-06],
       [ 9.7603e-02,  1.9542e-06,  9.7603e-02,  1.9542e-06],
       [ 1.9770e-01,  2.0952e-06,  1.9770e-01,  2.0952e-06],
       [ 2.9758e-01,  2.1637e-06,  2.9758e-01,  2.1637e-06],
       [ 3.9787e-01,  1.4734e-06,  3.9787e-01,  1.4734e-06],
       [ 4.9795e-01,  1.3670e-06,  4.9795e-01,  1.3670e-06],
       [ 5.9790e-01,  2.0252e-06,  5.9790e-01,  2.0252e-06],
       [ 6.9817e-01,  2.1771e-06,  6.9817e-01,  2.1771e-06],
       [ 7.9837e-01,  1.2704e-06,  7.9837e-01,  1.2704e-06],
       [ 8.9822e-01,  2.1794e-06,  8.9822e-01,  2.1794e-06],
       [ 9.9847e-01,  1.4442e-06,  9.9847e-01,  1.4442e-06]])

np.column_stack((res, arr))
```

gives:

```
array([[-2.7532e-03,  1.1973e-06, -2.7532e-03,  1.1973e-06],
       [ 9.7603e-02,  1.9542e-06,  9.7603e-02,  1.9542e-06],
       [ 1.9770e-01,  2.0952e-06,  1.9770e-01,  2.0952e-06],
       [ 2.9758e-01,  2.1637e-06,  2.9758e-01,  2.1637e-06],
       [ 3.9787e-01,  1.4734e-06,  3.9787e-01,  1.4734e-06],
       [ 4.9795e-01,  1.3670e-06,  4.9795e-01,  1.3670e-06],
       [ 5.9790e-01,  2.0252e-06,  5.9790e-01,  2.0252e-06],
       [ 6.9817e-01,  2.1771e-06,  6.9817e-01,  2.1771e-06],
       [ 7.9837e-01,  1.2704e-06,  7.9837e-01,  1.2704e-06],
       [ 8.9822e-01,  2.1794e-06,  8.9822e-01,  2.1794e-06],
       [ 9.9847e-01,  1.4442e-06,  9.9847e-01,  1.4442e-06]])
```

Comment: @hpaulj: I had never set a dimension to 0 but it does work fine!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using pandas and just appending the data to a dataframe in the for loop and then concat the data afterword. So something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

AJ=[]

for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    Dev1['SMU2'].oneshot(i)
    results = vstack([Dev1[smu].oneshot(v) for v in volts])
    AJ.append(results) 

AJ=pd.concat(AJ)
```

Note that after the for loop the AJ will just be a dataframe of dataframes that can be combined in many different ways. For more info this website is useful https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: What does `AJ` start as?

Comment: My apologies AJ is just an empty dataframe to begin with

Comment: Looks more like a empty list.